# Find the all possible multiples( size of n ) of a positive integer k

Tags: algorithm, combinations

**Input 1 :**

```
64
```

**Output:**( size of 3 )

```
1 x 1 x 64  =64
1 x 2 x 32  =64
1 x 4 x 16  =64
1 x 8 x 8   =64
2 x 2 x 16  =64
2 x 4 x 8   =64
4 x 4 x 4   =64
```

**Input 2 :**

```
6
```

**Output:**( size of 2 )

```
1 x 6  =6
2 x 3  =6
```

I tried Using Complete Binary Tree but  I didn't get all possible Combination
.

Here is :

```
                             64

                    32                  2

              16          2         2       1

           8     2     1    2     1   2   1    1
```

If Your trace level by level elements only some combinations are available

```
64 x 1 X 1
32 X 2 X 1
16 x 2 x 2
8  x 2 x 2 x 2( limit > 3 )
```

Question is I need all possible combinations

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need the all possible combination to form a number K(by product of number) that is eg:4=1 x 4 and 2 x 2. 8=8 x 1 , 4 x 2 , 2 x 2 x 2.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment: the question is typical of that sort of problem, and you've provided absolutely no code at all to show us what you've done so far.  Per the [Stack Overflow what's on topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."  Please provide what you've done so far, and what's causing problems.

Comment: You allowed 1 X 64 and also 2 X 2 X 16. So shouldn't 1 X 1 X 64 also be valid output? What is your rule for create the combination?
Simple recursion should solve this...

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. This site is not about giving you a straight answer to a generic problem, but about helping you when you're stuck with a specific problem. Please add what you tried, where you're stuck and what doesn't work.

Comment: I had added what i tried .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion method. Consider the following PHP code (I guess you can convert for the idea to each language you need):

```
    function comb($num, $cnt, $prefix, $minDiv) {
        if ($cnt == 0)
        {
                if ($num == 1)
                        return rtrim($prefix,",");
                else return false;
        }
        $arrs = array();
        for ($i=$minDiv; $i <= $num; $i++) {
                if ($num % $i == 0) { // if num modulo i equal 0
                        $ans = comb($num/$i, $cnt-1, $prefix . $i . ",", $i );
                        if ($ans) // if valid combination add it
                                $arrs[] = $ans;
                }
        }
        return $arrs;
}


$ans = comb(64,3, "",1);
echo "ANSWER:\n";
echo print_r($ans);
```

This code will generate the following answer for comb(6,2, "", 1):

```
1,6
2,3
```